# Trouble with combine class

Tags: article, journal, combine

What I want to do is combine several articles to form single journal volume. After some googling I found a class named `combine` seemingly suitable for the task. Unfortunately I had a trouble compiling very minimal code below

```
\documentclass{combine}

\begin{document}
    Some text
\end{document}
```

The error message I get is 'Extra \endgroup. \begin{document}'. I don't know what's going on here. How can I solve this problem? Or, is there a better alternative for `combine`?

Comment: `combine` needs an update.  Meanwhile adding this should work around the problem: `\makeatletter\@ifclasslater{combine}{2010/07/11}{\errmessage{No longer needed.}}{\AddToHook{env/document/begin}{\begingroup}}\makeatother`

Comment: This is explained further by the package author in an answer to a more recent question: ["Extra \endgroup" error when using the combine document class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591145/extra-endgroup-error-when-using-the-combine-document-class)